# I want to store component.ts data in to another variable and i want to convert into Global Variable

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

```
get_update(id:any): Observable<any[]>{


      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/vendor/'+id,options)
                        .map(response => response.json())                        
                        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.statusText));     


}
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit()
{ this.service.get_update(this.user).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

component.ts datas to be stored in another variable

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to achieve, your attempt, and why what you tried didn't work

Comment: This is not good practice but you can try: `window.data = data`; or you can use `localStorage` to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a data member in your class and use it, and for sharing data you can use `@input()` decorator `@output`decorator or use a service.

```
    export class AppComponent {
      constructor(){}
      public data=[];//


    ngOnInit()
    { this.service.get_update(this.user).subscribe(data => this.data=data);
}
```